# Почему media print работает только в комбинации клавиш Ctrl+P а не через js?

Tags: javascript, css

файл print.css стиль работает только когда вызываю печать Ctrl+P если вызываю печать через написанный код js изменений нет ни каких.

```js
function PrintElem(elem) 
  { 
    Popup($(elem).html()); 
  } 
  function Popup(data) 
  { 
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'table', 'height=1000,width=1000'); 
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
  
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body ><table>'); 
    mywindow.document.write(data); 
    mywindow.document.write('</table></body></html>'); 
    mywindow.document.print;
    mywindow.document.close(); /
    mywindow.focus(); 
    mywindow.print(); 
    mywindow.close(); 
     
  }
```

```css
@media print {
    body {
        color: #000;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="/project/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"  type="text/css" >
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Печать" id="pr" onclick="PrintElem('#table')" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавил несколько строк, старые закомментировал. У меня все работает.

```
<script>
function PrintElem(elem) 
  { 
    Popup($(elem).html()); 
  } 
  function Popup(data) 
  { 

$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" />');
  //  var mywindow = window.open('', 'table', 'height=1000,width=1000'); 
//    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');

 //   mywindow.document.write('</head><body ><table>'); 
 //   mywindow.document.write(data); 
//    mywindow.document.write('</table></body></html>'); 
     setTimeout(function() {
        window.print();
    }, 1000);
//    mywindow.document.close(); 
//    mywindow.focus(); 
 //   mywindow.print(); 
//    mywindow.close(); 

  }

</script>
```

Comment: вставил вашу строчку, но стиль так и не подключился.

Comment: 1. Jquery подключен? 2. Точный путь к css? Попробуйте адрес с http://

Comment: 1. Да подключен. 2. Да точный путь. не помогает

Comment: Если посмотреть код страницы, которая выдается на печать - там тоже нет CSS для печати?

Comment: тоже нету css стиля, хотя до этого работал и я ни чего в коде не менял. Блин как намучился с этим(

Comment: ошибка была в @media print, поменял так `@media print and (color) {
   table {
     background-color: red !important;
   }
} ` в режиме ctrl+p у таблицы стал красный фон

Comment: Сейчас поменяю ответ на рабочий вариант.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55116/discussion-between-labris-and-).